# Get correct window width after resize or orientationchange event for Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, android

I bound functions to the resize and orientationchange event. In this function i'm trying to read the windowwith. Iphone always gives me the correct sizes but Android devices (2.2, 2.3 and 4.0) seem to trigger the event before actually changing the windowssize. So I always get the last windowsize and not the newest. Is there some way (without timeouts) to get the correct windowsize?

I tried following attributes / functions:
    $(window).innerWidth(true)
    $(window).outerWidth(true)
    screen.width
    $(window).width()

None of them are giving the correct width.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Up to now, I see no other solution than doing a timeout for 500ms...

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately window.orientation is already updated when the onorientationchange event fires. So as a workaround I switch on that:

```
switch(window.orientation) {
    case 90:
    case -90: // portrait;
        h = Math.max(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        w = Math.min(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        break;
    default: // landscape
        h = Math.min(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        w = Math.max(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        break;
}
```

Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: It's the opposite:  on mobile portrait is 0 and landscape is -90 or 90